# storing information in nodes traversing them

Tags: java, tree, big-o, nodes

I was tasked to create a tree that stores fibonacci numbers. I previously recycled some code used to create a tree full of names and the key for each node. I can't seem to figure out why when I perform any traversal it doesn't print out the key of the node and value stored. I feel like I am missing something so simple. Well thank you for your time! OR maybe I am misunderstanding the assignment. I do not expect a direct answer since this is pertaining to my education!

original instructions

> Create a binary tree that stores your calls. How many calls will each internal node make? How many internal nodes will you have for a recursive version of the solution? Now, how big is that number? What if you call 5 “n” and think of Fib(n). What is the runtime complexity of your solution? Do you think you can do better if you simply do away with the recursion and calculate the Fibonacci series iteratively? Write a non-recursive solution and perform a similar analysis on it. How many lines of code would you execute in terms of “n”? Is it better or worse? Why do you think this is true?

```
class Node {
    int key;
    int value;


Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;

Node(int key, int value) {

    this.key = key;
            this.value = value;

  }
 }
```

and this is the rest

```
package bigobinarytree;

public class BigOBinaryTree {

Node root;

public void addNode(int key, int value) {
        Node newNode;
        newNode = new Node(key, value);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } 
            else {
        Node focusNode = root;
        Node parent;
        while (true) {
            parent = focusNode;
            if (key < focusNode.key) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } 
                            else 
                            { 
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;           
                if (focusNode == null) {

                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return; 
                }

            }

        }
    }

}

public void inOrderTraverse(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {
        inOrderTraverse(focusNode.leftChild);
        System.out.println(focusNode);
        inOrderTraverse(focusNode.rightChild);

    }

}

public void preorderTraverse(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {
        System.out.println(focusNode);
        preorderTraverse(focusNode.leftChild);
        preorderTraverse(focusNode.rightChild);


    }

}

public void postOrderTraverse(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {
        postOrderTraverse(focusNode.leftChild);
        postOrderTraverse(focusNode.rightChild);
        System.out.println(focusNode);
    }

}

public Node findNode(int key) {

    Node focusNode = root;
    while (focusNode.key != key) {
        if (key < focusNode.key) {
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

        } else {
            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        }
        if (focusNode == null)
            return null;
    }

    return focusNode;

}

    public Node findValue(int value) {

    Node focusNode = root;
    while (focusNode.value != value) {
        if (value != focusNode.value) {
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

        } else {
            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        }
        if (focusNode == null)
            return null;
    }

    return focusNode;

}

    public boolean remove(int key) {
    Node focusNode = root;
    Node parent = root;

    boolean isItALeftChild = true;

    while (focusNode.key != key) {

        parent = focusNode;

        if (key < focusNode.key) {

            isItALeftChild = true;

            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

        } else {
            isItALeftChild = false;
            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        }
        if (focusNode == null)
            return false;

    }
    if (focusNode.leftChild == null && focusNode.rightChild == null) {
        if (focusNode == root)
            root = null;

        else if (isItALeftChild)
            parent.leftChild = null;
        else
            parent.rightChild = null;

    }

    else if (focusNode.rightChild == null) {

        if (focusNode == root)
            root = focusNode.leftChild;

        else if (isItALeftChild)
            parent.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;
        else
            parent.rightChild = focusNode.leftChild;

    }

    else if (focusNode.leftChild == null) {

        if (focusNode == root)
            root = focusNode.rightChild;

        else if (isItALeftChild)
            parent.leftChild = focusNode.rightChild;


        else
            parent.rightChild = focusNode.rightChild;

    }

    else {

        Node replacement = getReplacementNode(focusNode);

        if (focusNode == root)
            root = replacement;

        else if (isItALeftChild)
            parent.leftChild = replacement;

        else
            parent.rightChild = replacement;

        replacement.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;

    }

    return true;

}       

public Node getReplacementNode(Node replacedNode) {

    Node replacementParent = replacedNode;
    Node replacement = replacedNode;

    Node focusNode = replacedNode.rightChild;

    while (focusNode != null) {

        replacementParent = replacement;

        replacement = focusNode;

        focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

    }

    if (replacement != replacedNode.rightChild) {

        replacementParent.leftChild = replacement.rightChild;
        replacement.rightChild = replacedNode.rightChild;
    }

    return replacement;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigOBinaryTree theTree = new BigOBinaryTree();

                int fib1=1, fib2=1, nacci=1; 
                int key = 0;

                    for (int i=3; i <= 50; i++ ){

                     nacci = fib1 + fib2; 

                        fib1 = fib2;

                        fib2 = nacci;

                        theTree.addNode(key, nacci);

                        key++;

                        }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("preorderTraverse");
            System.out.println();
            theTree.preorderTraverse(theTree.root);
            System.out.println("___________________");        

}   



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right, it was something simple, which is bittersweet. You've called

```
System.out.println(focusNode);
```

However, for Objects (like focusNode), `System.out.println()` automatically calls that Object's `toString()` method. For most Objects, that just means print out their Object ID, and also for most Objects, that's not super useful. Not for programs like this at least. The good news, though, is there are two fixes! First, you could override your Node's `toString()`. Like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Key:" + key + " Value:" + value;
}
```

You'd just put that in the Node class. Then, every time you called `System.out.println(focusNode)`, under the hood it's actually printing the output of your `toString()` method in the Node class. Alternatively, instead using:

```
System.out.println(focusNode);
```

you could just use:

```
System.out.println("Key:" + focusNode.key + " Value:" + focusNode.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You invokes the preorder method in your main method.

```
if (focusNode != null) {
    System.out.println(focusNode);
    preorderTraverse(focusNode.leftChild);
    preorderTraverse(focusNode.rightChild);


}
```

Does that give you any output? If you get some output, based on your code it will be only the standard toString() method of the focusNode object. If you want print out field values of the object like the key, you have to access these fields or overwrite the toString() Method. Like:

```
System.out.println(focusNode.key);
```